# Preventing Threads from Unnecessarily Executing Costly Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I want to protect access to a resource in the following manner:

- All threads can read concurrently, except during update (if the update is not atomic).
- Only one thread can be assigned the task of updating, until next time an
  update is required.

This may seem like a simple question of using a proper `lock`, or possibly making all operations atomic, but that is not it, I think.

If I just have a write-lock for updating (i.e. `ReaderWriterLockSlim`), or use non-locking code, nothing prevents more than one thread from running the update procedure (or queuing up to do so). If I use locking to block threads before checking if the resource need updating, they can't execute concurrently but are effectively serialized.

I could have specific threads performing all of the checking and updating of the resource, and utilize something like a `ManualResetEvent` to put other reading threads on hold until updating is finished. (Or if the updating is implemented as an atomic operation, just settle for having specific update threads.)

However, I'm uncertain about best practice, and I would like to ask if you think that the requirements may be met with less effort, or if I'm way off in any of my assumptions.

Comment: Strange question.  If your threads are so unruly that you cannot ensure in your code that you only ever start the one that performs updates just once then you also cannot guarantee that they are well-behaved and use the RWLS correctly.  Adding extra locks just buys you deadlock.  This just is never a real problem, don't make it one.

Comment: Why would you assume to have control over the threads accessing the instance? And please feel free to explain how you could determine that "this just is never a real problem". Seems like a strange comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. Use the exclusive lock mode for writing.

Comment: I know about the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` class, but I fail to come up with a usage pattern that prevents threads queuing up to perform unnecessary updates, even with exclusive lock mode for writing. That's what I'm trying to explain in my question - "If I just have a write-lock for updating [...] nothing prevents more than one thread from running the update procedure (or queuing up to do so)".

Comment: I overlooked that. Try to acquire the write lock with zero timeout and skip the update in case the lock is busy.

Comment: I get your thinking, but that thread still needs a value to return. So, I would need to go back and try again, possibly entering "update mode" several times, until the the "first thread" is finished updating the resource. Seems a bit unclean to me. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I see the issue. Make the writable resource a `Lazy<T>`. One writer can create a new lazy under the write lock and immediately exit. Then, any thread whoever comes first forces the lazy to run. All thread pick up the same value when done.

Comment: Interesting. I wouldn't have thought to use the `Lazy<T>` class for this. I'll have to give it a try. Would you update your answer with a code snippet, please, so that if I settle for this to be my accepted answer, others may more easily see why?

Comment: I'll leave it at explaining the concept.

Comment: As I understand you suggested solution, I would create a new `Lazy<T>` every time the resource needs to be updated, but the actual work is deferred to when the resource is accessed. I don't see how I can prevent several threads from creating new instances of `Lazy<T>`, but I assume you're thinking that this is OK, as long as the costly work is performed only once for every update cycle, correct? Then after returning, exiting the write-lock, any thread that updated the resource would immediately race to access the resource, though triggering the work load but once?

Comment: Lazy is only executed once so that's OK.; It's new to me that there is such a thing as an update cycle. So far I was only concerned with ensuring a single writer at a time. What triggers your "update cycle"? You can track the cycle number using an integer on any other "token". Writers would only create a new lazy when they are first in the new epoch.

Comment: Maybe you should explain your actual scenario.

Comment: By "update cycle" I just meant to say "every time an update is needed and performed", as per my second requirement: "Only one thread can be assigned the task of updating, until next time an update is required."